# AWS SDK is unable to execute HTTP request to get metadata from S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

First of all I've seen questions similar to mine but everywhere problem was the input stream that was not closed properly. My question is different.

I found the error at the middle of stress test (We use S3 actively)

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Too many open files"
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1201)"
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1147)"
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)"
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)"
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)"
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)"
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)"
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)"
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)"
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5054)"
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5000)"
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1486)"
at com.A.B.C.aws.s3.AwsS3Downloader.downloadObject(AwsS3Downloader.java:38)"
at com.A.B.C.aws.s3.AwsS3Util.getFileMetadata(AwsS3Util.java:1251)"
```

First time I was thinking that I have somewhere stream that needs to be closed but that's not the case. I don't hold the input stream here. Therefore I do **NOT** close the S3Object.

```
 AmazonS3 amazonS3 = getAmazonS3(awsClientConfig, needCrossAccntAccess, forceRefresh);
 S3Object object = AwsS3Downloader.downloadObject(amazonS3, bucketName, key);
 fileMetadata = object.getObjectMetadata().getRawMetadata();
```

Maybe somewhere in the application I have the input stream that is not closing and eventually I have error during the http call?

Note: I don't use shared **AmazonS3** object.

Comment: Does this happen immediately (on your very first download) or have you done 1000s of downloads at the point this fails?

Comment: At the middle of stress test.  It happens one a month.  S3 is actively used so yes,   I would say after 10000s requests

Comment: Afaik it's safe to call the close() method on S3Object instances, even when it will have no effect. I'd be tempted to try that. Obviously, you should probably also pursue standard Java/OS techniques for identifying leaked file handles. Alternatively, if you can net this down to a simple Java client that uses the AWS SDK and you can repro the issue then it may be worth raising an issue at the SDK github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used several tools to identify the problem.

1. I created Custom metrics to monitor file descriptors for each process. I identified which process had the problem using AWS Cloud Watch Metrics. I created a shell script that was running every 15 seconds and using AWS CLI I'm sending data points to AWS Cloud Watch metrics.
2. I used the YourKit profiler to find out exactly where was the memory leak.

Eventually:

- I increased file descriptor size for the ECS Fargate environment because by default 1024 was a soft limit and 1024*4 was the hard limit. This is a memory-intensive app running on production.
- I identified places where streams were not closed. (the class was not closable and Java try-with-resources was not working/0.

Answer (score 0):

> First time I was thinking that I have somewhere stream that needs to be closed but that's not the case. I don't hold the input stream here. Therefore I do NOT close the S3Object

You should.

Per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3Object.html#getObjectContent--):

> The method is a simple getter and does not actually create a stream. If you retrieve an S3Object, you should close this input stream as soon as possible, because the object contents aren't buffered in memory and stream directly from Amazon S3. Further, failure to close this stream can cause the request pool to become blocked.

It's perhaps not obvious from this description, but this call does an HTTP `GET` on the object, which includes the object content.

If all you care about is the object metadata, then call [getObjectMetadata()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObjectMetadata-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)